# How do i update particular drop down/text box values inside while loop in php

Tags: php

[image: Output]

I am using php while loop to fetch the ticket details

Here I want to update ticket status for selecting drop down values to update the ticket status so how can i do individually while clicking update like to update that particular ticket number including the selected option values ..

I can get ticket number

```
 <a href="update-ticket-status.php?id=<?php echo  $row['ticketpostid'];?>
```

but QC_Status, Severity and note is not getting the entered values

Is there any solution in PHP

**Code**

```
    $sql ='SELECT * FROM `ticket_details` where `qc_by`=:id';
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(':id',$id);

            $query->execute();
            if($query->rowCount())
            {

            ?>
                 <tr>
             <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Ticket#</th>
              <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Subject</th>
              <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Created Date</th>

             <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Status</th>
              <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Department</th>
           <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">QC Flag</th>
            <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">QC Status</th>
             <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Severity</th>
              <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">Note</th>
           <th style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px;">View Ticket</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           <?php while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                    {
                                        ?>
             <tr style=" font-size: 13px; ">
             <td>  <?php echo $row['ticketid'];?>
              </td>

                     <td>  <?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                     <td>  <?php echo $row['ticket_created_date'];?></td>


                     <td>  <?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                       <td>  <?php echo $row['department'];?></td>
                        <td>  <?php echo $row['qc_flag'];?></td>
                        <td> 

                                 <select style=" font-size: 13px; " name="prev"   id="prev" class="form-control select"     >
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="1">No Error</option>
                                    <option value="2">Error</option>

                                     </select> </td>
                                     <td>
                                      <select style=" font-size: 13px; " name="prev"   id="prev" class="form-control select"     >
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="-5">-5</option>
                                    <option value="-4">-4</option>
                                    <option value="-3">-3</option>
                                    <option value="-2">-2</option>
                                    <option value="-1">-1</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>

                                     </select> 
                                     </td>
                                      <td>
                                       <textarea type="text"  class="form-control" id="note"  rows="1" name="note" placeholder="Note..." > </textarea>
                                      <a href="update-ticket-status.php?id=<?php echo  $row['ticketpostid'] ;?>&amp;qcstatus= &amp;&prev= &amp;&note= " style="float: right" >Update</a>


                                      </td>
                                                    <td> <a href="view-ticket.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['ticketpostid']); ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="color: black;font-size: 17px;"></i></a>  </td>

                                     </tr>


        <?php }}
```

So here i am planning to get the values from selected options to **Anchor tag** 
**view-ticket.php** 
is there any way..?

regards,
Darshan N

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Hint: you need to show us the code you're having issues with.

Comment: You cannot directly pass value in anchor tag , one way is using `jquery and ajax`, for getting that particular `select box value` ,because each row will have different value , so you can try using `.parent()` in jquery to find nearest select box value of that particular row ,and can pass these  values in `ajax` for further processing.

Comment: @Swati thanks for u r suggestion.., Can u share any demo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you want to get value of `severity` :

```
<td class="select">
   <select  name="severity" class="form-control select">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
</td>
<td>
   <a href="#" style="float: right" class="btn" data-value="<?php echo  $row['ticketpostid'];?>">Update</a>
</td>
```

In your jquery  on click of `update` :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn").bind('click',function(){

                //var abc=$(this).parent().find('td.select>select').val();//here we  are getting value of select box ,also here parent() is <td> and then we find <td class="select">

               var dropdownValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.select').val();  // updated one 

              var id =$(this).attr("data-value");//getting id
                if(abc=='select')
                {
                    alert("Please Select one value");
                }

                else{

         $.ajax({
             url:'yourphppage.php',
             method:'POST',
             data:{abc:abc},//here we passing value to php page 
             success:function(data){
                //do something after coming back (result)


             }
                }); 
    });  
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: Here i can get ticketid but select value is showing as undefined after else alert(abc); it will shows as undefined.., any mistakes..?

Comment: Show your code ? What did you try , because i have tested above code in my project already .

Comment: Same thing only and i tried       var vacc = $(this).parent().siblings("td.select").text(); So here returning all the drop down option values

Comment: It is working small correction on that script  var dropdownValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.select').val();   thank you,

Comment: Great then , now use same way to get both select values and pass it to ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.update', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.post({
                url: '/update-post',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Add `.update` class to all update button. and post in to a ajax all required data. you can use `data-` attributes. above code is a sample only.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but in ajax ticketid will show last values only not dynamic values.. is there any way to direct fetch selected values without clicking any button to pass another page through <a> tag..?

Comment: please post your code as well, then only i can help you.